# Initialize WordPress customizer variables

Tags: theme-customizer

I have recently starting integrating the wordpress customizer into my theme.

Given the fact that i already had a theme options page, i use these values as default values of my new options (in the add_setting parameter).

All my new options are held into a variable called 'theme_options' which is an array of values.

The problem i have is that a user has to visit the customization page and click "save" on his first install to populate the 'theme_options' variable.

I am wondering if there is a way to initialize this field on theme activation directly (just like many theme options framework do).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that all you need to do is pass defaults to [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

```
function init_theme_options() {
  // check to see if theme options are set
  // Not sure how your options are organized but...
  $defaults = array(
    'opt1' => 'stuff1',
    'opt2' => 'stuff2'
  )
  $theme_options = get_option('theme_option_name',$defaults);
}
```

If you want to see a very complicated version of this, look at [how Twenty Eleven does it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/inc/theme-options.php).

Comment: Thank you ! I think you're right, it should be done with get_option.